# Get first element of a key using localStorage.getItem

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I was reading the country of the visitor from local storage using localStorage.getItem
I was reading this info directly form Google CMP.

```
console.log("Country code: " + localStorage.getItem('vpb-location'));
var countrycodeckeck = localStorage.getItem('vpb-location');

if (
    countrycodeckeck !== "PH" && //philippines
    countrycodeckeck !== "TH" //thailand
) {
```

The problem is that now Google changed the key from vpb-location to vpbg and now contains more info.

Example:

```
var countrycodeckeck = localStorage.vpbg;
console.log(countrycodeckeck);
```

*{"countryCode":"PL","isEU":true,"ts":1641125302501}*

Can you please tell me how to modify our code to check the “countryCode” stored in the local storage?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [Using the Web Storage API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) + [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 2):

The data in  the storage key is encoded as JSON. To access the information you need to decode the JSON to usable JavaScript with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
// Get the data from the storage.
const vpbg = localStorage.getItem('vpbg');

// Only proceed of there is actually data.
if (vpbg !== null) {
  // Parse the JSON to an object.
  const data = JSON.parse(vpbg);
  
  // data is now an object with properties that you can access.
  const countryCodeCheck = data.countryCode;

  if (
    countryCodeCheck !== "PH" && //philippines
    countryCodeCheck !== "TH" //thailand
  ) {
    // Do something if it checks out.
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You further append it with a dot to access those properties:
`localStorage.vpbg.countryCode`

Comment: var countrycodeckeck = localStorage.vpbg.countryCode;
console.log(countrycodeckeck);

returns undefined

Comment: @AndreaDeDonatis Please read the links in my comment

Comment: I appreciate your links but I am not sure I have the competencies to understand all. I will study it anyway but also hope to have support here.

Comment: @AndreaDeDonatis See the first link...

Answer (score -2):

```
Object.entries(localStorage)[0][0]
```

Comment: There’s already a well explained answer. Please explain how this is solving the question and inform about the downsides of getting the value by index.